# The benefits of switching access BackEnd to sql express

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-server-express

I have an access DB, which is split into a Backend and Frontend, that has c.a 100000 records in 60 tables.

I have this idea, that I can switch my Backend to a MSSQL Server Express.

I would like to know if it is worth the effort to attempt this idea. And which advantage do I have if my Backend is SQL Express and Front End access.

Thank you for your ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how many users are concurrently using your database and if your backend is located on a LAN or is a local database. 
The number of records (100000) are not so much for Access to handle.

If your database is on a LAN location or if you have concurrent users, you should get some advantages moving to SqlServer, but some plumbing and rechecking of your code will be required.

Remember, Access is fast and easy to build application with, but, at its core, is a personal database adapted to work for low concurrency situations. Sometime (and I tend to blame the programmer instead of Access itself) it is not suitable for concurrency use. If your application is critical then, as with every database solution, a good disaster recovery plan and quick maintenance intervention time are mandatory.

Comment: Hi steve,thank you for your answer. Backend located on a LAN and 2 or 3 user are simulationaly using DB

Comment: These specs are well inside the capability of Access. But, when you have concurrency, it is always a good idea to switch away from a file based database like Access.

Comment: Do not forget that SQL Server requires someone who knows what they are doing to look after it, Access requires very little.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely worth swapping to a version of SQL Server or MySQL. It can take a while to get the hang of once you have migrated from Access but using MS Sql Server will allow you to import tables easily and you'll have a more future proof application. Worked well for us

Comment: For 2 or 3 users and 100000 records? I would say it depends on the level of expertise in the organisation.